# strange class behavior in the python pattern decorator

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class, decorator

I want to impose a Berserk effect on the hero. 
Abstract classes: AbstractEffect and AbstractPositive (class heir), can accept the base parameter. Next, AbstractNegative will also be created. I am not sure whether the inheritance scheme is correct (Hero ---> AbstractEffect).

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod 
class Hero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = {"HP": 128}
    def get_stats(self):
        return self.stats.copy()

class AbstractEffect(ABC):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base
    @abstractmethod
    def get_stats(self):
        return self.base.stats()

class AbstractPositive(AbstractEffect):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base
    @abstractmethod
    def get_stats(self):
        return self.base.stats()

class Berserk(AbstractPositive):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base
        self.stats= self.base.stats
        self.stats["HP"] += 7
    def get_stats(self):
        return self.stats


hero = Hero() 
brs1 = Berserk(hero) 
print('brs1', brs1.get_stats()) 
brs2 = Berserk(brs1) 
print('brs2', brs2.get_stats()) 
print('brs1', brs1.get_stats())
```

I want to receive

```
brs1 {'HP': 135}
brs2 {'HP': 142}
brs1 {'HP': 135}
```

but I get

```
brs1 {'HP': 135}
brs2 {'HP': 142}
brs1 {'HP': 142}
```

what's my mistake?

Comment: Its difficult to know what you really want, but the effect is that both `Berserk` wrappers just reference the `stats` attribute of the original `Hero`. Each `Berserk` increments the same `"HP"` entry, so you should find that all three instances with have: `stats["HP"] == 142`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bacause of the following code

```py
self.stats = {"HP": 128}
```

{"HP": 128} is a container
and,

```py
self.stats = self.base.stats
```

Therefore,
when you use Berserk(heroxxx) to enhance hero, `self.stats["HP"] += 7` is actually modifying the original data. So you need to change it to `self.stats = self.base.get_stats()`,then you can get what you want. You can use the following code to test.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class Hero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = {"HP": 128}
    def get_stats(self):
        return self.stats.copy()

class AbstractEffect(ABC):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base
    @abstractmethod
    def get_stats(self):
        return self.base.stats

class AbstractPositive(AbstractEffect):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base
    @abstractmethod
    def get_stats(self):
        return self.base.stats

class Berserk(AbstractPositive):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base
        self.stats = self.base.get_stats()
        self.stats["HP"] += 7

    def get_stats(self):
        return self.stats.copy()


hero = Hero()
brs1 = Berserk(hero)
print('brs1', brs1.get_stats())
brs2 = Berserk(brs1)
print('brs2', brs2.get_stats())
print('brs1', brs1.get_stats())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been cruelly assaulted by *passing by reference*.

In your code, you have `self.stats = self.base.stats`. This does not make a copy. Therefore, `self.stats` for `brs1` and `brs2` refer to the *same* `dict`. When you instantiate `brs2`, you change it, and that change is reflected in `brs1`.

`self.stats = self.base.stats.copy()` would be a good start, *if* you don't want this to happen.

That said, I find it rather strange that you want to code status effects in this way...if it were me, I would have each status effect contain only a modifier, and it would be up to the character class to handle resolving those modifiers in turn.

Comment: @hyper Show what?

Comment: ...if it were me, I would have each status effect contain only a modifier, and it would be up to the character class to handle resolving those modifiers in turn...